# Finding conditions on real numbers to make their sum and difference an integer

Tags: number-theory

I m actually working on a problem and I am stuck somehow but I will be able to move on if I can figure out the following question.

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. I need $$2a, 2b,  a+b, a-b $$ all to be integers. What are the restrictions that I can place on $a,b$? Or let me say what are the conditions that I need to place on $a,b$. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $2a, 2b$ you need both $a$ and $b$ to be either integers or half odd integers.  Then from the sum you need both to be the same among integers and half integers.  The difference doesn't give you anything new as $a-b=(a+b)-2b$ so if both terms on the right are integers so is the one on the left.

Comment: I.e., $a,b \in \{\ldots,-1.5,-0.5,0.5,1.5,\ldots\}$ or $a,b \in \{\ldots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\ldots\}$.

Comment: Thank you guys. One more question please. Am i allowed to call the set $$ \{....., -1.5,-0.5,0.5,1.5, ...\} =\frac{ \mathbb{Z}}{2}?$$

Comment: I just realised that I am wrong.

Comment: I think its $$\mathbb{Z} + \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @Jaynot: that only gets you the case $a,b$ both half odd integer.  It misses the case where both are integer.  David has it right.